# Class having static member of its own type

Tags: java

```
class ABC {
    int x;
    static ABC y = new ABC();
}


public class XYZ {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ABC q = new ABC();
        q.x = 5;
        System.out.println(q.x);
    }

}
```

Can someone explain what all happens (step by step) when the code is run.

Also, when the `static` keyword is removed before the instance `y`, *StackOverflow* error takes place. Why does this not happen when the `static` keyword is present?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that your homework, what don't you understand with this code precisely?

Comment: If you remove `static`, then each `ABC` instance has it's own `y` field, meaning that for every `ABC` instance that is created, an new `ABC` instance is needed for the `y` value, so it creates a new `ABC` instance, which needs a new `y` value, so it creates a new `ABC` instance, which needs a new `y` value, so it creates a new `ABC` instance, which needs a new `y` value, so it creates a new `ABC` instance, which needs a new `y` value, so it creates a new `ABC` instance, which needs a new `y` value, `StackOverflowError`!!!

Comment: It's like trying to use the SingleTon pattern improperly :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static` means that a single instance of the variable is used across multiple referencing objects (in this case, `y`).

A `static` field lives in the context of the `class`, meaning all instances of the class will point to the same `static` object instance.
In a scenario of:

```
ABC a = new ABC();
ABC b = new ABC();
System.out.println(a.y==b.y);
```

The print will result in `true`, because the instances of `y` on both `a` and `b` point to the same object.

Non-static fields get populated with heir own individual instances; meaning that in a scenario of:

```
ABC a = new ABC();
ABC b = new ABC();
System.out.println(a.y==b.y);
```

(in a hypothetical scenario where such wouldn't trigger a StackOverflow) would result in `false`, because `a.y` would ***not*** be the same instance as `b.y`; each would have their own independent instances of `ABC` in their `y` fields.

A `StackOverflow` will happen without the `static` keyword because when ABC is instantiated, it needs another ABC instance for it's `y` field, which, when instantiated, creates another ABC, and so on, infinitely (until the stack is overflown).

With `static`, a single static instance of ABC, let's call it `sABC` is created, and it's own `y` field just references it itself, so the infinite loop of instantiation doesn't happen.

Comment: Thank You for your help. Could you also tell me what would the object `q` look like.. i mean would it have the object `y` in it or only have the integer `x`?

Comment: All instances of `ABC` would have a `y` field. The difference is in what that `y` object points to. In `q` (the instance you create in your main), it points to `y` (a static, second instance, which is instantiated when q is instantiated, because of `static ABC y = new ABC();` inside the definition of what a `ABC` class is.)... In `y` (instance), the `y` (field) points to the `y` (instance) itself. If `y` isn't static, `y` instance will populate it's `y` field with a new instance, which needs another instance for it's own internal `y` field, which needs one for it's `y` field, and so on...

Comment: @AayushTaneja I've edited the answer to attempt to make things clearer for you. If you still don't understand, I'd strongly recommend (re-)reading the basics on OOP.

Answer (score 0):

When the class loader loads this class it will immediately create an instance of this class and assign it to the class variable y. This is because y is declared static.
If you don't declare y static then you sayint that every instance of class ABC has an attribute y which is also an ABC. You are then also saying that the y attribute has to be assigned a new instance of class ABC, so this instance is created for you whenever you explicitly create an instance of ABC, as you do in your first statement in main(). Do you spot the recursion? That leads to a stack overfow.

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is a class-level variable.

Instance variable is object-level variable.

If you removing `static` keyword - this class trying instantiate itself and endless loop occurs, while static variable creates one instance one time and it's shared between all objects.

Stack memory keeps local variables and function calls, so it's overflowed because you have endless calls.

Answer (score 0):

## The Walkthrough

```
ABC q = new ABC();
```

Create a new instance of the `ABC` class called `q`

```
q.x = 5;
```

Set `q`'s property `x` to `5`

```
System.out.println(q.x);
```

Print the value held by `q`'s property `x` (should be 5)

## Static

The `static` keyword means that every instance of a class shares that same variable. When you create an instance of the class `ABC`, it contains another instance of `ABC` as the variable `y`. When you create another instance of `ABC`, it also has a variable `y`, but that variable is the same as the `y` held by the first instance of `ABC`.

If you were to remove the `static` keyword, `y` would not be shared by each instance of `ABC`. When you created an instance of `ABC`, it would create its own `y`, and that `y` would create its own `y`, and so on until you run out of memory and a `StackOverflow` error occurs.